# SQL statement to retrieve all data or transactions from database of a particular Id and plot same on a graph in asp.net

Tags: c#, sql

Below is the description.

```
    **Table**

        Pid memberId   name    date       taxAmount
        1    04        Sam    1/1/16      £10
        2    07        John   1/4/16      £12
        3    04        Sam    2/5/16      £17
        4    06        Paul   3/5/16      £10
        5    04        Sam    5/6/16      £10
```

Say I want to retrieve Sam's or any other persons' transactions from the database in Asp.net. Please what is the sql statement?

Sorry guys,please below is my complete code. I tried it but it didn't work.I would be glad is someone can help.

```
 {
     OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Myconnection"].ConnectionString);
                    try
         {



    conn.Open();


    string checkuser = "select count(*) from RegisteredMember where firstName='" + txtFirstName.Text + "'";


   OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(checkuser, conn);
   int temp = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
                       conn.Close();

     if (temp == 1)
       {
        conn.Open();
        string checkUserIDQuery = "select memberID from RegisteredMember where firstName='" + txtFirstName.Text + "'";
         OleDbCommand IDcmd = new OleDbCommand(checkUserIDQuery, conn);

                           string memberID = IDcmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
                           if (memberID == txtUserID.Text)
                           {
                               Session["New"] = txtUserID.Text;

        OleDbCommand Plotcmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;

        string query = "select * from payment where memberID= "+ txtMemberID.Text + "'";

        cmd.CommandText = query;    
        OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Chart1.Series["Tax History"].Points.AddXY(reader["date"].ToString(), reader["taxAmount"].ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is one extra space in your query after txtMemberID.Text. Also from where this cmd object came? Didn't you get any error here?

Comment: Where is cmd object declared? and what is the use of Plotcmd ? Try modifying your query to `string query = "select * from payment where memberID= '"+ txtMemberID.Text + "'";` and command to `OleDbCommand cmd= new OleDbCommand();`

Comment: Please post your full code

Comment: Please post the exception as well, so we at least have some idea about the issue that you are having.

Comment: if memberId is an int on the db then you should not wrap txtMemberID.Text in single quotes when building string query. So you can remove + "'" from the end of the line

Comment: @thinkpossible : Hello ! newbie, it's always good to refer this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  ,before posting your question,so you can get your answer fast and as per expectation.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: Please I have posted the codes. Thanks

Comment: Please I have posted my complete codes, please take a look at it. I would be glad is someone can help profer solution or spot the error in the code.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
string connString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=E:\Shamila Stuff\campus\semester 2\comp 1551-Application and Web Developement\asp\fwp\fwp\FwpDatabase.accdb"; // put your path
myConnection = new OleDbConnection(connString);

string query = "select * from payment where memberID= '"+ txtMemberID.Text + "'";
 if (myConnection == null)
                myConnection = GetConnection();
            OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(myQuery, myConnection);

            try
            {
                myConnection.Open();
                myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Write(ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                myConnection.Close();
            }
            try
            {
                myConnection.Open();
                OleDbDataReader reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

                if (reader.HasRows == true)
                {
                    reader.Read();

                    string myQuery1 = Chart1.Series["Tax History"].Points.AddXY(reader["date"].ToString(), reader["taxAmount"].ToString());

                    myCommand = new OleDbCommand(myQuery1, myConnection);
                    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    reply = true;

                }
                else
                {
                    reply = false;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                myConnection.Close();
            }
```

Put your connections string for the database in the mentioned place.

Comment: Please I have posted my complete codes, please take a look at it. I would be glad is someone can help profer solution or spot the error in the code.Thanks